# Coverage expects a test case for an @abstractmethod

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest, abc

As you can see in the picture below, coverage wants me to write a test case for the method inside the abc.
But I dont know how to do it, I mean as far as I can see there is nothing to test.

[image]

Code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class BaseVPS(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def create_server(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Correct, there's nothing to test. Coverage tools just report which lines are and aren't reached by the tests that run while they're instrumenting the implementation, not whether it is necessary to actually reach those lines (at this or any other level of test). It doesn't _"want"_ you to cover it, it's just telling you that you didn't.

Comment: `create_server` should be implemented in the derived classes, you can test it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since testing something like an @abstractmethod is unnecessary, we can add this configuration file to the root of our project to add exclusions to the coverage.

**pyproject.toml:**

```
[tool.coverage.report]
exclude_also = [
    "@(abc\\.)?abstractmethod",
    ]
```